# @2x.png require non-@2x.png sizes as well?

Tags: iphone, ios

I just had my app rejected, stupidly i uploaded a new version before I screen grabbed what exactly the exact wording was. But it was something along the lines of the app not running well on both the iPad and the iPhone 3g resolutions.

So my question is this. Am I required to include a scaled down graphic for every @2x size that I have? Because it runs on simulator and devices just fine... so i dont exactly get it.

Thanks!

Comment: If you don't provide non-hires versions, your app will not run on iPhone 3gs and iPad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite simply, yes you do! If anything the @2x graphics are optional

Comment: :( unhappy... then why does it still run fine on iPhone 3 Devices?

Comment: It shouldn't do! Are you running an adhoc build to test at all? If not you should as straight from Xcode pushes deltas to bring down compile time

Answer (score 0):

**10.3** Apps that do not use system provided items, such as buttons and icons, correctly and as described in the [Apple iOS Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Introduction/Introduction.html) may be rejected